# Get internal R functions to use my S4 method

Tags: r, oop, r-s4, r-s3

I've created a custom S4 class, and the idea is that it represents a vector that's always sorted, so I don't want `sort()` to actually do anything to it. So I defined a stub version of `sort()` for my class:

```
MyClass <- methods::setClass("MyClass", slots=list(x="numeric"))
setMethod("sort", signature(x="MyClass"), function(x, ...){}) # Do nothing
```

Then, I want to calculate a quantile of my class. R's `quantile()` function internally calls `sort()`. However, the `sort()` used inside `quantile()` is *not* aware of my S4 method, because it dispatches using `UseMethod()` (the S3 dispatcher) and *not* `standardGeneric()`, the S4 dispatcher. This is demonstrated below:

```
options(error=traceback)
instance = MyClass()
quantile(instance, 0.5)
```

This returns a call stack like this:

```
5: order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)
4: sort.default(x, partial = unique(c(lo, hi)))
3: sort(x, partial = unique(c(lo, hi)))
2: quantile.default(instance, 0.5)
1: quantile(instance, 0.5)
```

Since `sort.default` is being called, it is evident that my custom `sort` implementation isn't being used.

Is there a simple way to get R to use my S4 method here? I realise I can also define `sort.MyClass` (the S3 way), but if I do this, what is the point of having an S4 method at all? It seems like S4 is incompatible with core R methods which renders it fairly useless.

Answer (score 0):

Object `instance` is defined with a slot named `x` that is numeric. When you call `quantile(instance, 0.5)`, R do not know that you want `quantile` to act on the slot `instance@x`.
**Approach 1**:

```r
MyClass <- setClass("MyClass", slots = list(x = "numeric"))

setMethod(
    "quantile",
    signature(x = "MyClass"),
    function(x, ...) {
        callNextMethod(x@x, ...)
    }
)

# test drive
instance <- MyClass(x = c(0, 5, 2, 1, 3))
quantile(instance, 0.5)
sort(instance) # error
mean(instance) # error

# see that quantile is now using S4 dispatch
quantile
standardGeneric for "quantile" defined from package "stats"

function (x, ...) 
standardGeneric("quantile")
<environment: 0x000001fe1375fe08>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods(quantile)  for currently available ones.

# see method table for quantile
showMethods(quantile, includeDefs = TRUE)
Function: quantile (package stats)
x="ANY"
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("quantile")


x="MyClass"
function (x, ...) 
{
    callNextMethod(x@x, ...)
}
```

With this approach, you can see that `quantile` is automatically converted to using S4 dispatch.

1. The call `quantile(instance, 0.5)` is dispatch to `quantile,MyClass-method`
2. Inside `quantile,MyClass-method`, the code `callNextMethod(x@x, ...)` will dispatch to `quantile,ANY-method` with **content of slot `x` as argument**. This argument is numeric.
3. Inside `quantile,ANY-method`, the code will S3 dispatch the calling arguments to `quantile.default`.

However, This approach require you to specify a customized version of every functions to act on `MyClass`. Therefore `sort(instance)` and `mean(instance)` output error.

**Approach 2**:  Make `MyClass` as a subclass of `numeric`. Then all functions that work on `numeric` will work on `MyClass`. Below, I add a customized `initialize` method to automatically sort its numeric argument. A `sort,MyClass-method` to do no sorting and only return `MyClass` as `numeric` for consistency.

```r
MyClass <- setClass("MyClass", contains = "numeric")
setMethod("initialize",
    signature(.Object = "MyClass"),
    function (.Object, ...)
    {      
        callNextMethod(.Object, sort(..1)) # ..1 is first element of ... see ?dots
    }
)

setMethod(
    "sort",
    signature(x = "MyClass"),
    function(x, decreasing = FALSE, ...) {
        as(x, "numeric")
    }
)

# test drive
instance <- MyClass(c(0, 5, 2, 1, 3))
quantile(instance, 0.5)
quantile(instance)
mean(instance)
sd(instance)
plot(instance)
```

**Note**:

```r
setMethod("sort", signature(x="MyClass"), function(x, ...){}) # return NULL
setMethod("sort", signature(x="MyClass"), function(x, ...) x) # return x unchange
```